# Estimating the growth of a function

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose one has a positive and not necessarily integrable function $\alpha : [0,T) \to \mathbb{R},~T>0,$ satisfying the following inequality
$$\int_0^te^{C_1(t-s)}\alpha(s)ds \leq e^{C_1t},~\forall t\in [0,T),~C_1 > 0.$$

My goal is to estimate the growth of $\alpha$. I don't now if it is possible, however, let us assume that it holds the Mean Value Theorem for integrals, then $\exists \tau_t\in [0,t]$ such that
$$\int_0^te^{C_1(t-s)}\alpha(s)ds =te^{C_1(t-\tau_t)}\alpha(\tau_{t}),$$
therefore,
$$te^{C_1(t-\tau_t)}\alpha(\tau_t)\leq e^{C_1t}.$$ In this sense,
$$\alpha(\tau_t) \leq e^{C_1\tau_t}t^{-1}.$$

So this is some kind of conclusion about the growth. My question is, does this define the behavior of $\alpha$ on the whole $[0,T)$? Can it happen that for some point this estimate does not hold? Or if is yes, can I measure the size of such points?

If this approach wont work, anyone have other idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The initial inequality simplifies to
$$
\int_0^t e^{-C_1s}\alpha(s)ds \leq 1.
$$
It doesn't allow us to tell much about the pointwise behaviour of $\alpha$. Notice that  we can estimate
$$
\int_0^t e^{-C_1s}\alpha(s)ds \leq \int_0^\infty |\alpha(s)|ds,
$$
so your condition is satisfied by any integrable function on $(0,\infty)$ (after normalization).

Comment: I certainly agree with the first inequality and with the second, separately, but I don't see how you get the conclusion since the inequalities don't fit it other.

Comment: Oh, now I see. Do you think we can conclude that $|\alpha(s)|$ is integrable in $[0,\infty)$?, in this case it would follow that $|\alpha(s)|$ is finite almost everywhere, right?

Comment: The first inequality is equivalent to your initial condition. The second inequality in turn shows that any function $\alpha\in L^1((0,\infty))$ with $\|\alpha\|_{L^1(0,\infty)}\le 1$ satisfies the first inequality and consequently your initial condition. Thus your initial condition doesn't imply any pointwise bound on $\alpha$.

Comment: We can't conclude from the intial condition that $\alpha$ is integrable either. Note we can take for example $\alpha(s)=e^{C_1 s}\frac{1}{1+s^2}$, and then your bound holds, but $\alpha$ is badly divergent.

Comment: I see. The best thing I can conclude is that $e^{-C_1s}\alpha(s)$ is finite almost everywhere, right?

Comment: That's correct, at least we can say that $e^{-C_1 s}\alpha(s)$ is finite almost everywhere (and consequently $\alpha$ is finite almost everywhere, of course ;] ).

Comment: this kind solves my problem. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome :]